# "vous ne laisserez pas que de m'estimer"

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, négation, double-négation

I'm reading *Les Trois Mousquetaires*, and I'm having trouble with this sentence. I take it to mean something like "you'll esteem me all the same". WordReference says that "ne pas laisser de" is a dated (vieilli) way to say "never cease doing", but I'm confused how the "ne... pas que" negation fits in.

Comment: As guillaume says, it is a very old fashionned sentence. I'm native french and I didn't know what it meant until now...

Comment: You will never cease esteeming me.

Answer (score 5):

**Ne pas laisser de = Ne pas cesser de.**

C'est une expression vieillie, qui ne s'emploie plus.

On trouve aussi: **Ne pas laisser que de**, sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_laisser_de):

> C’est une aventure **qui ne laisse pas que d**’avoir un air singulier. —
>
> (Marivaux, La Surprise de l’amour, Acte III)
>
> Cela **ne laisse pas que d**’être gracieux. — (Marivaux, Le jeu de l’amour et du hasard, Acte III)

Le [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/laisser) confirme aussi cette forme, tout en précisant qu'elle est moins correcte:

> "Il ne faut pas laisser que de s'écrire de temps en temps", [Sévigné,
>   31 déc. 1684]
>
> "La constance d'Alcibiade ne laissa pas que d'être ébranlée par ce
>   coup", [Rollin, Hist. anc. Œuv. p. 630, dans POUGENS]

Answer (score 3):

The form with an added *que* is an older variant which has the same meaning, *que* means *but*.

From the [cnrtl "laisser" entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laisser)

> II. − Littér. **Ne pas laisser de** + inf. Ne pas cesser de, ne pas manquer de (sert à exprimer une affirmation renforcée, notamment dans un contexte d'opposition = néanmoins, pourtant, n'en... pas moins). Ce qu'il y a de certain, c'est que je ne laisserai jamais de m'employer, pour vous, à tout ce qui pourra vous être utile (Chateaubr., Corresp., t. 3, 1822, p. 156). La vie de la duchesse ne laissait pas d'ailleurs d'être très malheureuse (Proust, Temps retr.,1922, p. 1015):

10. J'étais bien décidé à ne pas souffler mot de mon histoire; mais la certitude que ma mère allait me demander des éclaircissements ne **laissait** pas de m'exaspérer. Duhamel, Confess. min.,1920, p. 30.

− Vieilli et plus recherché. **Ne pas laisser que de** + inf.Même sens. Le contraste de ce ton crayeux avec la couleur brune et foncée des poutres, des toits et du balcon, ne laisse pas que de produire un bon effet (Gautier, Tra los montes,1843, p. 18). Les hommes de 1793 ne laissaient pas que d'avoir leur bon côté pour les Bourbons (Mme de Chateaubr., Mém. et lettres,1847, p. 58):

11. Margaritone, (...) nouvellement établi dans la ville (...) y remarqua [dans l'atelier d'un jeune peintre] une madone encore toute fraîche, qui, bien que sévère et rigide, grâce à une certaine exactitude dans les proportions et à un assez diabolique mélange d'ombres et de lumières, ne **laissait** pas que de prendre du relief et quelque air de vie. France, Île ping.,1908, p. 151.

In your example, *vous ne laisserez pas que de m'estimer* is close to "you will never cease doing anything but esteeming me". A [Three Musketeer's translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1257/1257-h/1257-h.htm#the-audience) shows "you will not esteem me the less for it".

Both expressions are rare nowadays but still sometimes used, especially *ce qui ne laisse pas de me surprendre* = *which never cease to surprise/amaze me*.

Comment: Very helpful, and thank you for the links!